# C# MVC How to get data by id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Simple question. I am trying to change my method and rather than getting all values, I want to return values by id.

My current method returns all meetings from the database:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
    {
        var meetingId = data.meetingId;

        List<MeetingObject> meeting = db.MeetingAObject.ToList<MeetingObject>();

        return Json(new { data = meeting }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I want to change it so it receives a parameter (meetingId) and returns only the data pertaining to that meetingid, I tried this but did not get far

```
public ActionResult GetDataById(Parameters data)
{
    using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
    {
        var meetingId = data.meetingId;

        List<MeetingObject> meeting = db.MeetingAObject.ToList<MeetingObject>();  << I am not sure how to change the code beginning here

        return Json(new { data = meeting }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I think I made it work in this fashion:

```
    public ActionResult GetMeetingById(Parameters data)
    {
        using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
        {
            var meetingId = data.meetingId;

            List<MeetingObject> meeting = db.MeetingObject.Where(x => x.MeetingID == meetingId).ToList();

            return Json(new { data = meeting }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your MyEntities class?

Comment: what type is meetingId ? long? int? string? an object?

Comment: @Leandro - meetingId is an integer.

Comment: how is the name of meetingid in the MeetingObject?

Comment: @Leandro - MeetingID

Comment: nice, please see my answer update, and tell me if something doesn't is like you want to do.

Comment: Sounds like you resolved it by replacing the `.ToList<MeetingObject>()` call with `.Where(x => x.MeetingID == meetingId)` - perhaps close the question?

Comment: you don't need to pass the entire object if you only need the id. If my answer it helps to you to update or found the resolution, it will be nice marked as answered. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a first attempt of answer, if you clarify your question or comment here, I'll glade to update this answer to be more specific or correct.

Let's suppose you receive the meetingid that you say is integer. (BTW Why parameter?)
Then you use it as condition of the query.
MeetingID and meetingId must be the same type, or you need a cast.

```
public ActionResult GetDataById(int meetingId)
{
    using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
    {

        List<MeetingObject> meeting = db.MeetingAObject.Where(m=>m.MeetingID == meetingId).ToList<MeetingObject>();  

        return Json(new { data = meeting }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do apreciate your answer, I just don't understand the part in which you get an int meetingId as function parameter, but then you assign data.meetingId.

Comment: @erasmocarlos sorry was a typo!!

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda!